# Sending HTML email using PHP: including the HTML file

Tags: php, html, email

I am trying to send email using PHP. The email is an HTML email with hundreds of line of HTML code (in file **email.html**). I don't want to write the whole HTML code in the PHP. How can I do it? Is my below method correct? Any better alternative?

My Code (PHP):

```
$email_text = file_get_contents('email.html');
$headers = "From:def@gmail.com";

mail('abc@gmail.com', 'Hello', $email_text, $headers);
```

My Email File (email.html):

```
<html>
     <body>
          <a href="http://google.com">Hello</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

**My problem:** I want to send an HTML email which will display HTML content. The HTML content is taken from a file called email.html.

**Note 1:** I have simplified my above code just for the clarity. Original code is having headers which will display HTML code correctly. Also the original HTML file is having hundreds of line and CSS styling. I have mentioned only few lines just to simplify.

**Note 2:** There are many duplicates of *sending email using PHP* but I couldn't find how to include a big HTML file in just one line of PHP code.

Comment: im not clear as to what the actual question is.

Comment: @Dagon: Edited my question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: above should work fine, are you saying it doesn't? If so in what way does it not work?

Comment: @Dagon above is working fine. Just looking for better alternatives.

Comment: better in what way? what's wrong with the above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update for updated question:**

If you don't want to include all that HTML in your PHP code, then yes `file_get_contents()` is a fine alternative.

---

You need to include the content type, and MIME version in the headers. This is charset UTF-8 also.

```
$headers = "From: $from <$from_email>\r\n". 
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" . 
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Thanks. But I am not asking how to send HTML email. I am asking how to get HTML email's content from an HTML file. Edited my question.

Comment: @iSumitG then you shouldn't have accepted this answer. I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259622/how-to-attach-html-file-to-email-using-content-taken-from-db-in-php might help someone else