# How to send an email using php with a file as a source

Tags: php, html, email

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300698/sending-html-email-using-php-including-the-html-file), but the result of the email is just a plain text version of the html.

I have a file called email.html.

This is the code I've used:

```
 <?php
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form>
  <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <?php 
  }
else
  {
  if (isset($_POST["from"]))
    {

    $email_text = file_get_contents('template.html');
    $headers = "From:my.email@domain.com";
    mail('another@email.com', 'Hi', $email_text, $headers);
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: `mail()` php manual example #4

Comment: the answer to the question you link to correctly tells you what headers to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `text/html` `Content-Type` header to your email.

```
$headers = "From: my.email@domain.com";
$headers.= "\nContent-Type: text/html";
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to send an HTML email? If so you should use phpmailer and not the php mail function.

Comment: Use this class https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. An example is on the page so I won't copy and paste here

Comment: The PHP mail function is more than capable of sending HTML emails. PHPMailer even uses the `mail()` function.

Comment: Very true Adrian but it constructs the headers so you don't have to and does a way better job with html encoding