# Attaching a file in email in html5 web page

Tags: javascript, html, email

I am attaching file in html web app using following code but it is not working

```
 <div class="email_pot">

<a href="mailto:eptt@att.com?subject=Enhanced Push-to-Talk&attachments=["js/data.js","js/data.js"]"></a>

</div>
```

For attach file i use following procedure as it is given below

```
      {
      "toEmail": "ToAddressEmail"
      ,"toName": "ToAddressName"
      ,"subject": "SubjectLine"
      ,"body":"BodyText"
      ,"bodyHtml":"HTML Body Text"
      ,"attachments":["AttachmentPath","
      AttachmentPath"],"titleColour":"Hex Colour (i.e.FF0000)"
      }
```

Comment: can u clear your question? attach more code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259622/how-to-attach-html-file-to-email-using-content-taken-from-db-in-php

Comment: @Nileshpatel i have to use only this simple script not php or .net to send attachment

Comment: I think it's possible in PHP, but in JavaScript... I think not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attach File Through mailto URI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372036/attach-file-through-mailto-uri)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, **what's your question?** I will assume that you are getting some error when you tried to send the email. I have answered a very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13683183/670377) before:

According to [RFC 2368](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2368.html) **you can't add an attachment to a message with the mailto: URL scheme** due security reasons:

> The user agent interpreting a mailto URL SHOULD choose not to create a message if any of the headers are considered dangerous (...) Only the Subject, Keywords, and Body headers are believed to be both safe and useful.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can put a file attached to an e-mail depends on the mailer.
(but many mailers can't add attachement file from maito:protocol)

I think I was able to put the attachments in some versions of Outlook, perhaps.